# Imagem acima de 3000px não carrega no Wideimage

Tags: php, laravel, imagem, redimensionamento

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma função na qual é reponsável por pegar a imagem e redimensionar ela, porém imagens com 3000x2000 não são carregadas pelo WideImage

```
WideImage::load($ampliada)
            ->resize($largura, $altura, 'outside', 'center')
            ->crop('center', 'center', $largura, $altura)
            ->saveToFile($thumb, $qualidade);
```

Testei com outras imagens menores e funciona perfeitamente, existe alguma restrição no WideImage aonde não permite carregar imagens acima de uma quantidade de pixel?

Também tentei com o Intervention Image do Laravel

```
Image::make($ampliada)->resize($largura, $altura)->save($ampliada, 90);
```

Algumas vezes funciona e nas outras vezes me retorna o Erro 500, alguém sabe o porque disso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Tem que analisar as configurações do PHP!

Comment: A sua pergunta já foi respondida neste link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208439/php-resize-function-not-working-when-file-greater-than-2-mb